# C# User class. GetHashCode implementation

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I have simple class only with public string properties.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
    public string Field3 {get; set;}
    public List<SimpleClass> Children {get; set;}

    public bool Equals(SimpleClass simple)
    {
        if (simple == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return IsFieldsAreEquals(simple) && IsChildrenAreEquals(simple);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this); //Bad idea!
    }
}
```

This code doesn't return same value for equal instances. But this class does not have readonly fields for compute hash.

How can i generate correct hash in `GetHashCode()` if all my properties are mutable.

Comment: If a property is mutated, then the object is (presumably?) no longer equal to objects that it used to be equal to, so you just return a hash code based on the relevant properties to determine equality.

Comment: Why would the mutability of members be of importance for hash generation? You call `GetHashCode()` to determine a hash _for that moment in time_, not for the lifetime of that object. If you want the latter, then indeed you must make the properties read-only.

Comment: What does "correct" mean in your case? If all of your properties are mutable, and you use your `SimpleClass` as a key in a dictionary, what do you want to happen when one of those properties gets modified? If that causes the hash code to change, the dictionary will break. You may say "I won't do that", but you should be the one to actually say that, we shouldn't silently assume it.

Comment: compute hash once in constructor. put hash in readonly field. return the already computed hash from GetHashCode..... now no matter how your object changes. they will have hash of their first state.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That means two objects that compare as equal may have different hash codes, which is not valid for .NET objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [contract for `GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode) requires (emphasis mine):

> The `GetHashCode` method for an object must consistently return the same hash code **as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method**.

So basically, you should compute it based on all the used fields in `Equals`, even though they're mutable. However, the documentation also notes:

> If you do choose to override `GetHashCode` for a mutable reference type, your documentation should make it clear that users of your type should not modify object values while the object is stored in a hash table.

If only *some* of your properties were mutable, you could potentially override `GetHashCode` to compute it based only on the immutable ones - but in this case *everything* is mutable, so you'd basically end up returning a constant, making it awful to be in a hash-based collection.

So I'd suggest one of three options:

- Use the mutable fields, and document it carefully.
- Abandon overriding equality/hashing operations
- Abandon it being mutable

Comment: My problem is `ObjectListView` library (TreeViewObject instance) using this class in some internal hashTable: I don't know where and how. So, i must use it's classes in hashtable. But when i trying compute hash using mutable fields - `ObjectListView` except with `NullReferenceException`. Is only possible solution makes `SimpleClass` immutable?

Comment: @gek0n A NullReferenceException suggests you've just implemented it badly.

Comment: Yes. I doesn't understand how i can implement it in right fast-compute way (coz if i must get hashes from all children as in equal method, it wi be very slow). Any suggestions?

Comment: @gek0n Well you haven't shown us any of your code, and we don't know what your performance requirements are. Basically, so can't help without a more specific question. (Your claim about computing hashes of children being "very slow" sounds like an expectation rather than the results of testing...)

Comment: anyway, your answer is correct, and i mark it as "accepted".
My "very slow" is only expectation, coz i write some JsonEditor. And `SimpleClass` is a node in my own Json tree. It may have large deep of nesting, so i think iterate throw all children recurently is bad idea.

I think i try implement `SimpleClass` as immutable type or try write "normal" `GetHasCode()` method. 
Thanx